# What are Composite Renderings/Components in SXA

Tags: sxa, presentation

What are composite components or renderings in SXA?
(I'm looking for answers describing the inner workings, ideally).

I have read about [SXA composite components](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/getting_started_with_sxa/renderings/the_sxa_renderings_and_rendering_variants#_Composites) and [SXA composite renderings](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/composite_renderings). From what I can tell, this is not SXA-specific, but rather a type of rendering which uses a datasource containing multiple sub-items. Am I missing something here? From what I can see, they seem to be quite similar to Partial Designs (in having their own layout) but do not have a way to *edit* them in Sitecore.

**Edit:** On further examination, I see that the composite components have their own layouts, so probably are specific to SXA.

Comment: You might want to review http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2015/11/03/sitecore-composite-components/. I’ve used these on non-SXA projects successfully. They work very well. Verified on 8.2u5.

Comment: I have also used the composite components that @jrap mentions. Although it is worth noting that this is a very different thing to the composites in SXA. The one from Chris Van De Steeg have more in common with a Partial Design in SXA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SXA, composite components are ones that get layered together. Think of the Tabs or Accordion components. Each of these require you to add a primary component, then add secondary components. The experience may have improved between versions, but here is an example in SXA 1.6.

**Examples:** Tabs component.

[image]

[image]

Take notice how the **Tab** component contains **Tab Item 1** and **Tab Item 2**. Then nested in each is some text and an image.

[image]

Behind the scenes the data is stored like this:

[image]

**Note:** Snippet is the new kid on the block (1.6) to build your own composite components

Answer (score 3):

From the [Sitecore Documentation on Composite Renderings](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/composite_renderings):

> A composite rendering consists of several renderings. Each instance
>   can have its own layout and it can be designed separately in
>   Experience Editor. When a composite rendering is rendered on the page,
>   it queries each item from its data source and pulls data and layout.
>   This facilitates building very complex layouts, but also involves a
>   more advanced setup.

This is a concept that has been around in various forms for a while. I think Thomas Eldblom came up with the [first version](https://blog.eldblom.dk/2009/07/22/composite-layouts-%E2%80%93-keeping-your-stuff-together/) of it almost 10 years ago. SXA has refined the implementation and made it much more user-friendly.

Comment: I've read that very same article as well (I linked to it in the question!). I was hoping for an answer which would shine some light on how these are developed and their inner workings.

Comment: So you did. I only saw the first link. I guess I should read more carefully. Perhaps it would also be a good idea to specify that you are looking for implementation details in your question.